# (Co)limits in lax functor categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

Let $\mathcal I$, $\mathcal C$ be $2$-categories (or $(\infty, 2)$-categories, I'm interested in both cases) and assume that $\mathcal I$ is small, $\mathcal C$ has enough weighted (co)limits as you need. We can define the $2$-category of (co)lax functors $\operatorname{Fun}^\text{(co)lax}(\mathcal I, \mathcal C)$. (**Edit**: I wrote an incorrect description for this which is now deleted)

Is there a nice way to describe (co)limits in (co)lax functor categories? I don't expect it's too simple like the non-lax case (which is computed pointwise) because lax functors specialize to monads, and colimits of algebras are usually complicated. But more specifically:

1. Is there a known formula for them? By this, I mean an expression for enough data (value on cells under the diagram) in terms of, say, some weighted (co)limits in $\mathcal C$.
2. Are they simple to compute in some cases, e.g., filtered colimits?
3. In particular, if $\mathcal C$ is (co)complete, can we say that $\operatorname{Fun}^\text{(co)lax}(\mathcal I, \mathcal C)$ is (co)complete?

Comment: The internal hom corresponding to the lax Gray tensor product does not have lax functors for objects. It has ordinary functors for objects and lax natural transformations for morphisms.

Comment: Ah, thanks, my bad! I was confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what kind of morphisms between your lax functors you're interested in.  (As Tim says, lax functors are not the objects of the Gray internal hom.)

For any 2-category $I$, there is a 2-category $I'$ such that lax functors out of $I$ are the same as strict functors out of $I'$.  Thus, the 2-category of lax functors and *strict* natural transformations is equivalent to an ordinary $\rm Cat$-enriched functor category, and thus inherits all limits and colimits from its codomain 2-category $C$ computed pointwise.  In addition, it is strictly 2-monadic and 2-comonadic over a set-indexed power of $C$.

The 2-category of lax functors and *pseudo* natural transformations between them is equivalent to the category of algebras and pseudomorphisms for this 2-monad or 2-comonad.  Therefore, by the classical work of Blackwell-Kelly-Power on 2-monads (*Two-dimensional monad theory*), it has PIE-limits (using the monad) and PIE-colimits (using the comonad), again computed pointwise, and in particular all pseudolimits and pseudocolimits.

Similarly, the 2-categories of lax functors and lax or colax transformations are the categories of algebras and lax or colax morphisms.  Such categories don't in general have even all pseudolimits or pseudocolimits, but there are significant classes of limits and colimits that they do have -- again computed pointwise.  Steve Lack initiated this study in his paper [Limits for lax morphisms](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/%7Eslack/papers/talgl.pdf), and later he and I characterized precisely the class of limits that such 2-categories admit in our paper [Enhanced 2-categories and limits for lax morphisms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2111).

Note that all of these limits and colimits *are* computed pointwise.  It's true that colimits of monads *on a fixed category* are complicated, but here we are talking about (co)limits of monads *in a fixed 2-category* which are a different beast, and in particular involve changing the object *on* which the monad lives.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check those papers. I was confused and I actually meant to ask about (co)limits in Gray internal hom. I guess the last case (lax functors and (co)lax transformations) specializes to that question as well?

Comment: Yep, if you just skip the first step of passing from $I$ to $I'$, you can do all the rest of it  with strict 2-functors and the various kinds of transformation.

Comment: How is $I'$ constructed from $I$?

Comment: @PierreCagne The highbrow answer is that 2-categories are the algebras for a 2-monad on Cat-enriched graphs, and lax functors are the lax algebra morphisms, so you can apply the general theory of lax morphism classifiers for 2-monads (e.g. Blackwell-Kelly-Power).  Explicitly, the underlying 1-category of $I'$ is freely generated by the underlying graph of the underlying 1-category of $I$, and its 2-cells are generated by the 2-cells of $I$, the 'laxators', and the axioms of a lax functor, so that there is a universal lax functor $I\to I'$.

Comment: @MikeShulman Thanks a lot, I suspected something like the free generated category on the underlying graph by looking at the lax functors from the point just being monads, but couldn't make it work precisely. With your explanation, it is much clearer!